# Python: calculate angle and distance between two geocode points while changing on of the given point's Height

Tags: python, math, geocoding

I have three geocode points. I want to calculate the distance and angle (not azimuth) between each pair and treat them as in a sphere.

So far I've been using the mpu.haversine_distance to get the distance between them.

But what If I want to change one of the point's altitude and then calculate it's distance and angle?

Can it be changed?

[image]

I want to get the 50 deg angle.

Or if I'm dealing with highs of no more than 1400 meters and distances of less than 30 KM it won't even have that much effect on the angle?

And how can I test the angle output to see if it's accurate?

Comment: Altitude shouldn't have any influence on bearing angle. For the total distance, you can simply use Pythagoras.

Comment: You need 3 points to calculate an angle.

Comment: I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @yovelcohen: With angle, do you mean [bearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation))?

Comment: I want to treat them as three points of three-dimensional triangle

Comment: Do you have an example with three coordinates?